# Deploy a WebSphere Portal 6 portlet to WebSphere Portal 5

Tags: websphere, deployment, portlet, portal

I am using Eclipse 3.2.2 with WebSphere Portlet Factory Designer 6.0.2.

I have a portlet that was developed for Portal 6 which works fine, I can build the portlet War and deploy to a Portal 6 server fine.

However, we only have production servers running Portal 5.
So how do I build a War file which is compatible with Portal 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portal 5 is supported by PF 6.0.2 and I don't see why the portlet war file would depend on the portal version. Have you tried deploying the same war file on portal 5?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have since given up trying as we will be getting production servers which run Portal 6.

I had an error about a missing class when trying to deploy to Portal 5. I think if I had rebuilt the war file against WAS 5 and WPS 5 that it should have worked ok. That's what I was about to try before I was told not to bother anymore.